# Disable dark fading in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, navigation-drawer

Is there a way to disable the dark fading effect for the background view in the Navigation Drawer View in Android?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use `setScrimColor(int color)` method. As default color is used `0x99000000`. So if you don't want `faded` background, set `transparent` color in this method.

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: `getColor()` is deprecated. You can use: `mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent));`

Comment: The text colour got back to normal but the icons i have used in the items in the nav drawer are still kind of faded. Why so ?

Comment: Android/AndroidX Remove Background color and shadow On Navigation Drawer
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874165/4334920](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874165/4334920)

Answer (score 37):

Addition to koso's answer: you can directly call the colors from Color class like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 8):

> drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#99000000"));

// For dark fading effect

```
                            or
```

> drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#33000000"));

// For light fading effect

```
                            or
```

> drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

// For no Fading

Comment: This is helpful, but each line is missing a trailing closing parenthesis, and the final line should read `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a custom shadow:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```