# how to get transparent/translucent sidebar navigation android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want something like this:

[image]

I have no idea how to achieve that... any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set transparency of Navigation drawer background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808398/how-to-set-transparency-of-navigation-drawer-background)

Answer (score 0):

Try below way;

```
navigationView.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x80000000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```