# Android Remove Shadow On Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, shadow, drawer

[See here what i mean](http://marcoaprea.altervista.org/shadow.jpg)

Hi, I'm using stock Navigation drawer v4 and i ask how can delete that background shadow when navigation drawer is open.

this is my code of NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.trasparent, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And this is MainActivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 20):

I find the solution :D

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Adding this in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 10):

This is works for me in androidX

```
/*Navigation drawer with transparent background*/
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

/*Remove navigation drawer shadow/fadding*/
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerElevation(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setDrawerShadow method to point to a transparent drawable:

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.someDrawable, GravityCompat.START);
```

Comment: You'd still have the problem that newer versions of Android use elevation instead of Drawable shadow. That elevation can be set though: navigationDrawer.setElevation(0f);