# ReactNative : Remove shadow from DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: android, reactjs, drawerlayout, react-native

Is there a way to accomplish this :

[Android Remove Shadow On Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568530/android-remove-shadow-on-navigation-drawer)

in React Native ?

I see no properties for doing that in the [DrawerLayoutAndroid documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that the RN API does not offer a way to parametrize that property, but the `DrawerLayoutAndroid` component extends from the native `DrawerLayout`, and so you can just tweak a bit the source code to include the desired functionality. Have a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/drawer/ReactDrawerLayoutManager.java) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/drawer/ReactDrawerLayout.java).

Of course, messing around with RN's code might be a bit messy, so what you can do is just take those files and refactor them into a separate component that extends your functionality. I built such component and put it in a repo so that you can have a look. Here's the link: https://github.com/martinarroyo/DrawerLayoutNoShadow Particularly have a look at [this line](https://github.com/martinarroyo/DrawerLayoutNoShadow/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/drawerlayoutnoshadow/drawerLayout/DrawerLayoutNoShadow.java#L73).

I set the value to transparent, but you can put any other color you'd like and it should work. A very good idea would be to pass the value as a `prop`, but the essentials should be covered with the code in the repo.

Hope that helps.