# How to remove dark shadow from navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am a beginner in android development.I am very confused of seeing this shadow above booking details.i want to know what it is? And how to fix it?

[[image: 1]]

Comment: attach image for more details as what you looking for

Comment: post your xml...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Remove Shadow On Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568530/android-remove-shadow-on-navigation-drawer)

Comment: share your xml file

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide shadow from upper part of the drawer then ..

1) It is your actionbar drawn partially. so it is appearing as shadow.

2) to Remove that shadow , I had to apply `app:insetForeground="@null"` to the `NavigationView` in xml

Answer (score 1):

```
drawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Try this code .

Comment: @Suhail if this is working then you should accept it as answer.

Comment: it's not working man.I thought this was the answer.but i mistaken.I still have the problem.But I appreciate your efforts.Anyone Knows Correct answer please Tell me..

Comment: I had similar problem where I was getting weird "shadow" kind of dark border around outer edge of drawer layout. This fixed it. +1