# android studio sliding menu remove beneath black screen

Tags: android

Hi Im using android studio sliding menu. I manage to show the navbar after pressing menu. bu I want to disable the seme black screen at the back when nav is showing. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dark fading in Navigation Drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960548/disable-dark-fading-in-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are using DrawerLayout's DrawerListener,
if so.. then in onDrawerOpened() method you may hide the background view and then make it visible in onDrawerClosed() method .

For more info, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html